# Find correlation coefficient of two columns in a dataframe by group

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe "Im" that looks like this

```
        V1   V7   X134    X135    X136    X137   X138
      1 m  1000 543.360 1057.770 1869.42 2664.06 3935.307
      2 m  2000 767.256 1704.430 2993.63 5248.06 6341.129
      3 m  3000 413.096  796.168 1441.13 3500.46 2962.048
      4 a  4000 257.128  559.200 1014.79 2948.64 2080.437
      5 a  5000 188.504  440.640  813.60 2538.11 1639.349
      6 a  6000 483.704  921.064 1679.98 3626.44 3426.709
      ....
```

I want to find the correlation coefficient between column X135 and all the other numbered columns, so in other words, I essentially need this

```
        > cor(Im$X135,Im$X136)
        > cor(Im$X135,Im$X134)
        > cor(Im$X135,Im$X137)
```

The problem is I need the correlation grouped by "V1". The output I am looking for should be something like this (using hypothetical correlation coefficients)

```
        V1   cc134   cc136  cc137
      1 m    0.92    0.99   0.95
      1 a    0.99    0.93   0.89
```

I have looked at tapply, ddply, aggregate and everything I found was for row wise functions like sum and average, resulting in an output which has the same columns. I am new to R so couldn't figure out how to write a clever function to do this. I have considered reshaping the data, but didn't get anywhere with that either. Any and all help appreciated!

Comment: Try data.table. Also generally not good practice to use numbers as column names

Comment: Ahh thanks! Found the solution. Also the number column names were a side-effect of a previous data reshape, and I kind of figured they are not good practise since they are such a nuisance. I should probably edit the question and put in text ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of problem is best suited by `data.table` package.
Here is a simple attempt:

```
library(data.table)

data <- read.table(text="   V1   V7     134      135     136     137    138
      1 m  1000 543.360 1057.770 1869.42 2664.06 3935.307
      2 m  2000 767.256 1704.430 2993.63 5248.06 6341.129
      3 m  3000 413.096  796.168 1441.13 3500.46 2962.048
      4 a  4000 257.128  559.200 1014.79 2948.64 2080.437
      5 a  5000 188.504  440.640  813.60 2538.11 1639.349
      6 a  6000 483.704  921.064 1679.98 3626.44 3426.709",header=T)

data <- data.table(data)

setkey(data,V1)

data[,list(cc134=cor(X135,X134),cc136=cor(X135,X136),cc137=cor(X135,X137)),by=key(data)]
```

To learn more about the package:

```
vignette("datatable-intro")
vignette("datatable-faq")
vignette("datatable-timings")
```

Or see it in action:

```
example(data.table)
```

Comment: +1, you can use `setDT` to covert `data` from `data.frame` to `data.table` by reference.

Comment: Thanks @Arun for all the +1s :) and for the info about the `setDT` option. Didn't know about it.