# Correlations of a variable with multiple variables

Tags: r, dplyr, correlation

My input data `df` is:

```
Action          Difficulty  strings characters  POS NEG NEU
Field           0.635       7       59          0   0   7
Field or Catch  0.768       28      193         0   0   28
Field or Ball   -0.591      108     713         6   0   101
Ball            -0.717      61      382         3   0   57
Catch           -0.145      89      521         1   0   88
Field           0.28        208     1214        2   3   178
Field and run   1.237       18      138         1   0   17
```

I am interested in group-based correlations of `Difficulty` with the remaining variables `strings, characters, POS, NEG, NEU`. The grouping variable is `Action`. If I am interested only in the group **Field**, I can do `filter(str_detect(Action, 'Field'))`.

I can do it one by one between Difficulty and the remaining variables.
But is there a faster way to do it in one command with multiple variables?
My partial solution is:

```
df %>%
 filter(str_detect(Action, 'Field')) %>%
 na.omit %>%   # Original data had multiple NA
 group_by(Action) %>%
 summarise_all(funs(cor))
```

But this results in an error.

Some relevant SO posts that I looked at are: This is quite relevant to generate a correlation matrix but does not address my question [Find correlation coefficient of two columns in a dataframe by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23188643/find-correlation-coefficient-of-two-columns-in-a-dataframe-by-group). Useful to compute different types of correlations and introduces a different way of ignoring NAs: [Check the correlation of two columns in a dataframe (in R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64570922/check-the-correlation-of-two-columns-in-a-dataframe-in-r)

Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!

For reference, this is the sample `dput()`

```
structure(list(
Action = c("Field", "Field or Catch", "Field or Ball", "Ball", "Catch", "Field", "Field and run"), Difficulty = c(0.635, 0.768, -0.591, -0.717, -0.145, 0.28, 1.237), 
strings = c(7L, 28L, 108L, 61L, 89L, 208L, 18L), 
characters = c(59L, 193L, 713L, 382L, 521L, 1214L, 138L), 
POS = c(0L, 0L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L), 
NEG = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L), 
NEU = c(7L, 28L, 101L, 57L, 88L, 178L, 17L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Use group _by and then across. Or use by and sapply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try -

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  filter(str_detect(Action, 'Field')) %>%
  na.omit %>%   # Original data had multiple NA
  group_by(Action) %>%
  summarise(across(-Difficulty, ~cor(.x, Difficulty)))
```

If you don't want to `group_by` `Action` -

```
df %>%
  filter(str_detect(Action, 'Field')) %>%
  na.omit %>%  
  summarise(across(-c(Difficulty, Action), ~cor(.x, Difficulty)))

#    strings characters        POS        NEG        NEU
#1 -0.557039 -0.5983826 -0.8733465 -0.1520684 -0.5899733
```

Comment: Thank you @Ronak, is it possible to do the same but without group_by().
I see that the different variants of ```Field``` are kept separate because of group_by. I want them all to be reduced down to one.

Comment: Sure. You can remove the `group_by` line and use `summarise(across(-c(Difficulty, Action), ~cor(.x, Difficulty)))` instead. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying it on the main data.